# Shiurim by Rav Dovid Feinstein Zt"l

Tags: rabbis, adult-learning, recording

Does anyone know where I can find recorded shiurim by Rav Dovid Feinstein?

Comment: Kol Halashon has a few: https://www.kolhalashon.com/New/RavDaf/RavInfoD.aspx?RavID=2606&English=True&Lang=English.

Comment: I think that link is for Rav Dovid ben Rav  Yecheil Michel Feinstein, not Rav Dovid ben Rav Moshe Feinstein.

Comment: You can try calling the MTJ office. But in general Reb Dovid was very private about his shiurim and didn't want them publicized. In fact any shiur sent by email, for which the recipient needed express permission from Reb Dovid, comes with a warning not to share it. There are many years of video recordings of his Chumash shiur as well, but I think those were private funded, not sure what the point of those were. Hopefully those get released.